# How to implement Keycloak in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, security, adapter, openid, keycloak

Can anybody help me with the integration from Keycloak in to Angular 6 ? 
I don't know how I must start and how to initialize the Javascript Adapter

Comment: Hello Max. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some more information on what exactly are you trying to achieve here. Also, please add some sample code to work with. It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one. BTW, there's an Angular Implementation of Keycloak. You can find it here: **[`keycloak-angular`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular)**

Comment: Max to start , you can check quick start  tutorial https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-angular2

Answer (score 3):

I used this one: 
https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular

Every step described there, and an example how to integrate also included.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 8+ and Keycloak OpenId Connect for enabling REST Login, Logout, Check Session then you can use this angular dependency:

[Angular Keycloak Dependency for version 2+ tested for Angular version 8+](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-keycloak)

**Installation**

```
npm i ng-keycloak
```

**API**

```
import { NgKeycloakModule } from 'ng-keycloak';
```

**# Usage**

**Register the NgKeycloakModule in your app module.**

```
import { NgKeycloakModule } from 'ng-keycloak';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgKeycloakModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Use the import NgKeycloakService in your component.**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgKeycloakService } from 'ng-keycloak';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  username = 'YOUR_KEYCLOAK_USERNAME_TO_LOGIN';
  password = 'YOUR_KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD_TO_LOGIN';

  // The BASE_URL is empty in case the proxy-config is used from Angular to resolve the CORS error
  // If the CORS error is not present use the BASE URL as the keycloak url with the port number
  // Example BASE_URL = 'http://13.43.53.42:30224'
  keycloakConfig = {
    BASE_URL: '',
    realm: 'YOUR_REALM_NAME',
    clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    credentials: {
        secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
    }
  };

  constructor(private ngKeycloakService: NgKeycloakService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // You need to set the Keycloak Configuration using _setkeycloakConfig(config) method before you
    // can use the Library
    this.ngKeycloakService._setkeycloakConfig(keycloakConfig);

    this.ngKeycloakService.logout().pipe().subscribe(logoutSuccessResponse => {
      console.log('Logout Success Response', logoutSuccessResponse);
    }, (logoutErrorResponse) => {
      console.log('Logout Error', logoutErrorResponse);
    });

    this.ngKeycloakService.login(this.username, this.password).pipe().subscribe(loginSuccessResponse => {
      console.log('Login Success', loginSuccessResponse);
    }, (loginErrorResponse) => {
      console.log('Login Error Response', loginErrorResponse);
    });

    this.ngKeycloakService.isLoggedIn().pipe().subscribe(loginStatusResponse => {
      console.log('Login Check Status', loginStatusResponse);
    }, (loginStatusErrorResponse) => {
      console.log('Login Check Status Error', loginStatusErrorResponse);
    });
  }

}
```