# keycloak-angular : Events related to authentication

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-services

I want to monitor events related to authentication, as follows

> START, INITIALIZED, LOGGED_IN, LOGGED_OUT, TOKEN_REFRESHED, TOKEN_VALIDITY_CHECKED, TOKEN_EXPIRED, NOT_AUTHENTICATED
>   how can I do it?

I was using an explicit service for keycloak , when I started to use "keycloak-angular" I do not know how to monitor events

versions : "keycloak-angular": "^1.3.0" , Angular: "^5.2.9" and , keycloak server ; 3.4.2.Final

In the old service

**Declaration**

```
private eventStream: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('START');
private keycloakAuth: any;
```

**Initialization**

```
this.keycloakAuth = new Keycloak({
    "realm": this.configService.config.security.keycloak.realm,
    "auth-server-url": this.configService.config.security.keycloak.authserver,
    "ssl-required": this.configService.config.security.keycloak.sslRequired,
    "clientId": this.configService.config.security.keycloak.clientId,
    "public-client": this.configService.config.security.keycloak.publicClient
});
```

**use**

```
this.keycloakAuth.init({ onLoad: 'check-sso' })
    .success(() => {
        // Pour initialiser les champs nom d'utilisateur
        this.getInfosUser().then();
        // notify ...
        this.eventStream.next('INITIALIZED');
        if (this.keycloakAuth.authenticated) {
            this.logger.info('[KeyCloak] Init end, Already logged in !');
            // notify ...
            this.eventStream.next('LOGGED_IN');
        }
        else {
            this.logger.info('[KeyCloak] Init ended, not logged in !');
            // notify ...
            this.eventStream.next('LOGGED_OUT');
        }
        resolve();
        // if some call are waiting for end of initialization,
        // notify them that it has ended with success !
        this.notifyEndOfInit(true);
    })
    .error(() => {
        reject();
        // if some call are waiting for end of initialization,
        // notify them that it has ended with failure !
        this.notifyEndOfInit(false);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

For Keycloak OpenId Connect based Authentication where you can use REST based interface to Login, Logout and Check user session you can use this library in Angular which is shared in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59122397/10294152

You need to enable OpenId-Connect in your keycloak configuration in order to use it.